# How to add for format=json in oracle weblogic server

Tags: oracle, json, httpresponse, weblogic11g

I have installed oracle weblogic server 11g.Implemented RESTFul but as per document when I place there format=json. It should works but it is not working.

Can you please let me know, how to resolve response as json.

Answer (score 0):

you can get a working example of how to do this here: https://www.samplecode.oracle.com/sf/projects/oracle-parcel-svc/ and we have a webcast series that covers JAX-RS on WLS in Session 4 at this link:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/learnmore/weblogic-javaee6-webcasts-358613.html

When you configure your method that you want to return JSON from you have to specify that it produces JSON.  Here's one way to do it:

```
  @GET
  @Path("{id}.json")
  @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})  
  public Parcel getParcelById_json(@PathParam("id") int id)
  {
    return getParcelById(id);
  }
```

You also need to put the right HTTP headers in the client in order to specify that it expects a JSON response.  Some test clients like SOAP-UI auto-convert JSON to XML such that you can do an XPATH on it, even though the actual transmission of data is JSON.